# Continuous Deployment Bluemix with existing Bitbucket repo

Tags: bitbucket, ibm-cloud, continuous-deployment, devops

I'm experiencing an issue with Bluemix DevOps continuous integration system when it comes to linking the project to an existing private Bitbucket repository.
I tried the steps presented in this [link](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/27490/jazzhub-bitbucket/) and although I'm able to see the content of the Bitbucket folder, the devOps is still stuck to the initial commit and it does not take the appropriate files during the building stage.
Can anyone provide any tips or suggestions?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those instructions, although it mentions "private", are only valid for a Public repository, as you have noted without a similar style to the GitHub integration we don't have a way to setup a shared token you would need to be able to authenticate. That said today, you cannot really use a pull method to pull changes from BitBucket to DevOps Services, you will need to use a push method from somewhere that you can authenticate to your private repo and the DevOps Services git repo to keep them in sync.

https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/197619/continuous-delivery-with-bitbucket-and-jazzhub.html

Comment: Hi Joe, many thanks for your support. At this point I'll reconsider my approach.